# Internet solid in windows, but inconsistent in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I have a duel-booted PC that can either boot into windows 8.1 or Ubuntu 14.04. My internet is very responsive and solid in Windows, but incredibly patchy, intermittent and annoying in Ubuntu. Constantly disconnecting and reconnecting, apparently at random.

Hardware is:

Latoptop - `Acer Aspire E14`

Wireless Card - `Broacom 802.11n Network Adapter`

This isn't the case in windows, so I'm guessing the problem is software based. Is it possible to find my card's driver software in Windows 8.1 (how do I do this, where do I look?), copy it into my Ubuntu partition, and then use some sort of emulator to run my card using my windows driver under Ubuntu?

Comment: Does the Internet work at all? If not then you should give us ur computer brand and type and model and fish for drivers.

Comment: @RookieTEC9 Added hardware, thanks. And yes, the internet does work, but it's intermittent.

Comment: In duel booting, do they fight to the death? :)

Comment: @RonMaupin haha. Ubuntu wins :P (despite wireless problems)

Comment: If your looking for something to run .EXE (s) then use Wine, which you can download at the Ubuntu store. I have no clue whatsoever if that will do any good, though.